# Tax not showing on my website

Tags: magento-1.9

I have tried to create a new tax rule for my site, but there seems to be no Australian Options for me to pick in relation to our 10% GST.

Do I need to add something to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at this article on the Magento website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-vat-gst

OR

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/setting-magento-store-australia

These will get you a long way.